# Check whether a function is an isometry using definition

Tags: linear-algebra, isometry

Given the definition that a function $f: V\rightarrow W$ is an isometry iff the image of an orthonormal basis of V is an orthonormal basis of W, how do I know if matrix
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}$$
is an isometry if I don't know V and W?

Comment: I would guess $V=W=\mathbb{R}^2$ and the map to be considered is $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2,x\mapsto Ax$ (matrix multiplication)

Comment: I agree with @PeterMelech; this is a $45^o$ rotation matrix

Comment: May be a last little hint: $A^tA=I$.

Answer (score 0):

If $V$ and $W$ are not specified, you may assume that $V=W=\Bbb R^2.$

Note that the given transformation is a $45$ degree counterclockwise rotation, which preserves the angles and distances; hence, it is an isometry.

Comment: Would this be isometric if $f:(\mathbb{R^2},d_2) \to (\mathbb{R^2},d_2)$ where $d_2$ is of course the Euclidean metric?